# Prevent client-side caching of javascript within a static file

Tags: javascript, caching

I have a web app that makes assorted  calls to load in javascript.  i.e.:

```
 <script src="test.js"></script>
```

I know the common solution to prevent caching is this:

```
 <script src="test.js<?=$random_number?>"></script>
```

My challenge is that my app is not served up by a language like PHP/ASP.  It is basically just a flat file.  (Because we use the same source code as a PhoneGap app)

Is there a cleaner way to do a script tag other than below?

```
 document.write("<script src='test.js?rnd=" + Math.random() + "'></script>");
```

Answer (score -1):

use a dom script adder instead of document.write:

```
function addScript(u,d){(d=document).getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(d.createElement('script')).src=u}

addScript("test.js?rnd="+Math.random());
```

Comment: I gave this a try - it sorta works, sorta does.  It does add the scripts into the head, but they don't execute until after the document is fully loaded.  By then it is too late.  Thanks for trying, though.